# Django-channels: How to delete an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-channels

I'm making a real-time chat app using django channels.
I want to delete an object from database using django channels(actually deleting a message from the group). How can this be done?

This is my backend code:

```py
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

from .models import Room, Message

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(data)
        message = data['message']
        username = data['username']
        room = data['room']

        await self.save_message(username, room, message)

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username
        }))

    @sync_to_async
    def save_message(self, username, room, message):
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        room = Room.objects.get(slug=room)

        Message.objects.create(user=user, room=room, content=message)
```

Should i use javascript?

I tried to delete some objects by using Ajax but it didn't work.

Comment: try ```Message.objects.create(id=message_id).delete()```` where message_id is the id of the message you want to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use python methods to modify Django's database. You need to use decorator `@database_sync_to_async` above each method in your class so that the code running asynchronously begins a synchronous data process which generally takes longer and must be waited for using `await`.

First import:

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
```

Then design the method in the class:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def deleteRoom(self, roomID):
    room = models.SupportRoom.objects.get(pk=roomID)
    room.delete()
```

Then call the method from the receive method:

```
await self.deleteRoom(roomID)
```